# How add the two textbox value and pass to another textbox?

Tags: jquery

How to add my textbox 1 and 2 value and pass to textbox 3?

```
<input name="1" id="1" value="" >
    <input name="2" id="2" value="" >

        <input name="3" id="3" value="" readonly>
```

Here's my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Zy46N/6/

Comment: When Do you want to show the addition? On a click of a button or when you fill in both values?

Comment: @Rohan When I fill both value in textbox 3

Comment: `$('#3').val(parseInt($('#1').val()) + parseInt($('#2').val()));`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<kbd>[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/RL5uq/)</kbd>

Adding Two Strings with space separated.

```
var input = $('[name="1"],[name="2"]'),
    input1 = $('[name="1"]'),
    input2 = $('[name="2"]'),
    input3 = $('[name="3"]');
input.change(function () {
    input3.val(input1.val() + ' ' + input2.val());
});
```

---

Adding Two numbers

[isNaN()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN)

if It's not a valid Number take it's value `0`

<kbd>[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/RL5uq/1)</kbd>

```
var input = $('[name="1"],[name="2"]'),
    input1 = $('[name="1"]'),
    input2 = $('[name="2"]'),
    input3 = $('[name="3"]');
input.change(function () {
    var val1 = (isNaN(parseInt(input1.val()))) ? 0 : parseInt(input1.val());
    var val2 = (isNaN(parseInt(input2.val()))) ? 0 : parseInt(input2.val());
    input3.val(val1 + val2);
});
```

Comment: @TusharGupta, I am getting this error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }"

Comment: @TusharGupta, I followed the same. Kindly check my code here: https://jsfiddle.net/cdgrccb8/

Comment: @Aravin r u including jQuery ?

Comment: Yes, Included Jquery. I have updated that code  here: https://jsfiddle.net/cdgrccb8/. Actually, that textbox are in Bootstrap Model popup.

Comment: Same error @TusharGupta. "(index):548 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined"

Comment: @Aravin Include jQuery

Comment: @TusharGupta, I got it.. JQuery is called after this script section. Now, I changed the position. Now Working........ Thanks for your time bro..

Comment: @Aravin Great (y) Cheers .!!

Answer (score 4):

Use `class selector` for `textboxes` to add, use alph numeric `ids`. Use `parseFloat` to convert `text` to `number`.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Zy46N/10/)**

```
$('.common').change(function () {
    $('#id3').val(parseFloat("0"+$('#id1').val()) + parseFloat("0"+$('#id2').val()));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this in your javascript function.

```
var sum=$("#txtbox1").val()+$("#txtbox2").val();
// Assign sum to third textbox
$("#txtbox3").val(sum);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$('input').change(function() {
   $('[name="3"]').val(parseInt($("#1").val())+(parseInt($("#2").val())));
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Zy46N/8/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use val and change function from jquery

```
$("#1, #2").change(function(){
     var val1 = $("#1").val(),
         val2 = $("#2").val();
     $("#3").val(val1 + val2);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
    $('input').change(function() {
    if($('[name="1"]').val()!=="" && $('[name="2"]').val()!=="")
    {
   $('[name="3"]').val(parseInt($("#1").val())+(parseInt($("#2").val())));
    }
    else
    {
        $('[name="3"]').val("");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

your code itself is working and just need a little of changing.

```
$('[name="1"], [name="2"]').change(function() {
   $('[name="3"]').val($('#1').val() + $('#2').val());
});
```

Fiddle [sample.](http://jsfiddle.net/Zy46N/12/)